# Sqlite C# code works in Unity Editor, but stops working after compiling

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine, oculus

I run into the problem, that my Game works fine in the Unity 3d IDE, but the moment i compile it, it stops at a certain moment. In fact, when my sqlite code is executed. But not just at the initialization!

So this code runs just fine:

```
/// <summary>
/// Basic initialization of SQLite This will be activated by the manager script 
/// </summary>
public static void SQLiteInit ()
{
    string SQL_DB_LOCATION = @"URI=file:C:\temp\inlusio_data\InlusioDB.sqlite";
    mConnection = new SqliteConnection(SQL_DB_LOCATION);
    mCommand = mConnection.CreateCommand();
    mConnection.Open();
    ExecuteQuerry("PRAGMA page_size = " + "4096" + ";");
    ExecuteQuerry("PRAGMA synchronous = " + "1" + ";");
    mConnection.Close();
}
```

The ExecudeQuerry code seems to work fine, as the above part of my code worked. Here the ExecudeQuerry code:

```
    public static void ExecuteQuerry (string sqlcomand)
{
    Debug.Log(sqlcomand);
    mCommand.CommandText = sqlcomand;
    mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

problematic part, at which the game gets stuck:

```
public static void InitialSavingsToDB (string chiffre, string EasyDelay, string HardDealy, string session)
{
/// Subject code 
ExecuteQuerry("INSERT INTO 'Subject'('Subject_Number','EasyDifficultyLevel','HardDifficultyLevel') VALUES ('" + chiffre + "','" + EasyDelay + "','" + HardDealy + "');");
}
```

I tried it like this, too :

```
public static void InitialSavingsToDB (string chiffre, string EasyDelay, string HardDealy, string session)

{
    /// Subject code 
    mConnection.Open();
    mCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO 'Subject'('Subject_Number','EasyDifficultyLevel','HardDifficultyLevel') VALUES ('" + chiffre + "','" + EasyDelay + "','" + HardDealy + "');";
    mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


    mConnection.Close();
```

}

It is maybe worth mentioning, that i call the InitialSavingsToDB function from my ManagerScript, that is declared as

```
public class ManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {
...
...
...
private void Start ()
    {
        ...
        testofsql.SQLiteInit(); // initialisation of the Data Base
        ...
...
...

    }

...
...
}
```

So my code works fine, the data is saved perfectly when i test the Game from the Unity 3d Editor. The moment I compile it, it just does not continue ingame. No errors, nothing. I can even run around. But the game is stuck.

I honestly don`t knew how to solve this. Have googled since 2 weeks to make sqlite working in Unity, tried to avoid errors, debuged everything, till i found the source of the problem and am clueless ... i hope somebody can help.

Thank you very much!

Cheers,
petr

Comment: just as an side note, sometimes unity does not copy the dll's to the build folder. at least in the case of sqlite i used :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your the target platform? Android, IOS, ...?

Be aware, that for different platforms unity3d uses different sqlite assemblies.

Try to check the following project
https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d and compare data in Plugins folder with what is used in your project.

Comment: thank you! in fact the problem was exactly that the sqlite dll was not copied to the folder of the build. some strange bug, i guess. it was for desktop windows.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest trying to use a library designed for Unity. Personally this is what I have been doing to handle multi-platform SQLite handling. I would highly suggest this library/wrapper

SQLite made easy for Unity3d http://codecoding.github.io/SQLite4Unity3d

I am currently in the process of improving upon that and making it even more easy to work with. However this is probably a good starting point!

GOOD LUCK!